# obtain all possible combinations that give a total

Tags: python, combinations

I need to know how I can improve this code so that it shows me all the possible combinations of numbers that added together give the result I am looking for.

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULjd9.png)

```
import itertools
lista=[95.95, 73.35, 78.85, 78.85, 22.85, 90.45, 64.15, 88.45, 37.12, 90.45, 37.12, 37.12, 95.95, 14.18, 78.85, 78.85, 64.15, 90.45, 90.45, 56.08, 66.75]

valor=662.25
# Generar todas las combinaciones posibles
combinations = []
for r in range(len(lista)):
    combinations += itertools.combinations(lista, r)

# Comprobar si la suma de cada combinación es igual a la suma objetivo
result = []
for combo in combinations:
    if sum(combo) == valor:
        result.append(combo)

# Mostrar las combinaciones encontradas
if result:
    for combo in result:
        print(combo)
else:
    print("no se encontraron resultados")
```

In this case, when I run the program it tells me that it does not find any solution but it really does and it is this: [22.85 , 90.45 , 88.45 , 90.45 , 37.12 , 95.95 , 90.45 , 90.45 , 56.08]

Comment: Don't make us retype code from an image.  Post code as plain text.

Comment: done i forgot put a number

Comment: Due to inaccuracies in floating-point values, those numbers don't **exactly** add up to 662.25.  They actually add up to 662.2500000000001.

Comment: rather than posting your exact unique 30+ lines of code copied straight from your project, you should spend a few minutes abstracting your question into a simple generalized version. *Obtaining all possible combinations that give a total* does not require us knowing about the various if statements, print messages, input options, etc. that you have in your code. Not taking a few minutes to remove that unnecessary noise comes across as inconsiderate to the people who are helping you for free. Not saying you *are* inconsiderate (you're new, and writing questions is it's own skill), just advice.

Comment: ok, thanks I'll edit it now

Comment: I'm going to check the floating point thing, thanks @JohnGordon Do you have any bibliography to read more about it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/494134

Comment: All you need to do is check `target - sum < delta`.

Comment: Yes I already saw how I should, thank you

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar That's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem (now) is floating-point rounding error:

```
$ python
Python 3.8.10 (default, May 26 2023, 14:05:08) 
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = [22.85 , 90.45 , 88.45 , 90.45 , 37.12 , 95.95 , 90.45 , 90.45 , 56.08]
>>> print(sum(a))
662.2500000000001
```

Note: that is not exactly `662.25` so your test using `==` is most likely failing.

This is NOT a python bug.  Rather it is a consequence of how floating point arithmetic works on computers.  For more information:

- [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004). (The short answer is "No".  The long answer is many pages of mathematical analysis followed by "Therefore No".)
- [What Every Computer Scientist Should
  Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/800-7895/800-7895.pdf)

There are two approaches to solving this "problem":

1. Do a range test; e.g.  test that the absolute value of the difference between the two values is acceptably small:

   ```
   if abs(662.25 - sum(a)) < 0.005:
   ```

   This is a more Pythonic way:

   ```
   if round(sum(a), 2) == 662.25:
   ```

   (In general, the problem is knowing what the range test threshold should be.  Since your numbers seem to have 2 digits precision after the decimal point, rounding to 2 digits is appropriate in your case.)
2. Do the arithmetic using (for example) `decimal.Decimal`.  This will be more expensive, but you will get precise values.  (Unless you do division operations ...)

Comment: Thank you very much, I had no idea it worked like that.

Comment: I did this because for what I need it, you only work with two numbers after the comma:     '''if round(sum(combo),2) == valor:'''